# Substituir strings específicas no dataframe por valores vazios

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

estou com um arquivo .csv que estou tratando, e a coluna ap_residencia_estado deveria estar preenchida apenas com floats mas está preenchida com strings (mesmo os valores numéricos são strings) e os valores que deveriam estar vazios estão preenchidos com a string "N/D"

Gostaria de saber como posso filtrar e remover apenas os termos com a string N/D da minha coluna, preservando os valores numéricos que estão em formato string (Pretendo alterar todos para float assim que remover os N/D da coluna)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is_not_nd = df.ap_residencia_estado != "N/D"
df = df[is_not_nd]
```

A primeira linha retorna uma boolean serie contendo `True` para os valores que são diferentes de `N/D`.

Este filtro é utilizado na segunda linha para selecionar apenas os valores `True`.

Comment: Camarada, por alguma razão, seu código remove alguns dados do meudataframe, de 4027 linhas pra 9 colunas caí pra 3985 pra 9 colunas

Comment: Sim. Não era este o intuito? Remover as linhas com N/D? Você disse na sua pergunta: `Pretendo alterar todos para float assim que remover os N/D da coluna`. Não é possível remover os N/D da coluna sem remover a linha inteira do DataFrame, amigo. Caso contrário, você teria uma coluna com menos linhas do que seu DataFrame, e o pandas iria emitir uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Sim, era. Perdão, acho que expressei minha intenção de forma equivocada. 

Gostaria de remover a string que está preenchendo o valor da matriz, porém queria que aparecesse "nan" assim como está na outra coluna. Pra que apenas fique um valor vazio na matriz , não preenchido pela string N/D

Answer (score 0):

Irei testar seu método, mas também consegui resolver o problema fazendo esta técnica aqui. :)

```
#4) Convertendo os valores string em formato float e substituindo os valores N/D da coluna por valores vazios
df['ap_residencia_estadia'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ap_residencia_estadia'],errors='coerce')
```